# How to estimate the number of JVMs in WebSphere?

Tags: jvm, websphere

What parameters should be taken into account when reviewing the architecture of an application environment based on WebSphere Application Server? Let's assume I know the minimum requirements for the application (8BG RAM, 6GHz CPU) and the requirement is that the system should be able to handle 10 000 users at the same time. What are the single JVM limitations?

Answer (score 0):

To estimate the ability of WebSphere or any computing system to support some number of users with a given workload, you need to perform load tests on the system, with a load similar to that expected in production. During the load tests, collect platform resource usage data (cpu, memory, network, etc. - NMON works well for Linux) as well as Java resource usage data (garbage collection logs, thread pool usage, connection pool usage, etc.) Examine the resource usage information to identify resource bottlenecks which constrain the total system capacity, which may be relieved through tuning or may require provisioning of additional resources.